# Error in Logcat Android

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to get the answers from a form in an application with android.

Here is the code I used:

```
   package com.stage.sondage;



  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.RadioButton;
  import android.widget.RadioGroup;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class Questionnaire extends Activity {


EditText zone ;

RadioGroup mRadioGroup1;
RadioGroup mRadioGroup2;
RadioGroup mRadioGroup3;
RadioGroup mRadioGroup4;
RadioGroup mRadioGroup5;

RadioButton b1;
RadioButton b2;
RadioButton b3;
RadioButton b4;
RadioButton b5;

Button enregistrer;

//Création d'une instance de ma classe LivresBDD
     SurveyAdapter survey;
     Appreciation appreciation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.questions);


    // We get a reference on the radio-group widget
     mRadioGroup1 = ( RadioGroup )findViewById( R.appreciation.rep1 );
     mRadioGroup2 = ( RadioGroup )findViewById( R.appreciation.rep2 );
     mRadioGroup3 = ( RadioGroup )findViewById( R.appreciation.rep3 );
     mRadioGroup4 = ( RadioGroup )findViewById( R.appreciation.rep4 );
     mRadioGroup5 = ( RadioGroup )findViewById( R.appreciation.rep5 );

     b1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(mRadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
     appreciation.setRep1((String) b1.getText());
     b2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(mRadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
     appreciation.setRep1((String) b2.getText());
     b3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(mRadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
     appreciation.setRep1((String) b3.getText());
     b4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(mRadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
     appreciation.setRep1((String) b4.getText());
     b5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(mRadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
     appreciation.setRep1((String) b5.getText());

     zone = (EditText) findViewById(R.appreciation.zone);
     appreciation.setZone(zone.getText().toString());
    try{      

     enregistrer = ( Button )findViewById( R.appreciation.enregistrer);
    enregistrer.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick( View view ) {                                          

            //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
            survey.open();

            //On insère le livre que l'on vient de créer
            survey.insertAppreciation(appreciation);

            //on ferme la base de données
            survey.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Questionnaire.this,Questionnaire.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                }

            });


 }
    // If there is an exception, for example the database is not usable...
    catch ( SQLiteException e ) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Impossible d'ouvrir la base de donnees",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Problأ¨me... L'erreur vient probablement d'un fichier xml.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}



}
```

I want to get the answers from this form and return to the same form.

When I launch the application I get the following errors from the logcat:

> 07-30 00:59:00.577: E/AndroidRuntime(239): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting   due to uncaught exception
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stage.sondage/com.stage.sondage.Questionnaire}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at com.stage.sondage.Questionnaire.onCreate(Questionnaire.java:53)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
>             07-30 00:59:00.617: E/AndroidRuntime(239):    ... 11 more

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: What is line 53? and why are you surrounding your button onClick with a try catch?

Comment: i removed the try catch the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

Your survey variable is null because you do not initialize it. You just do this:

```
SurveyAdapter survey;
```

and leave it like that.

That's why you get NullPointerException error.

Comment: i changed the code however the problem remains
       SurveyAdapter survey=new SurveyAdapter(this);
       Appreciation appreciation=new Appreciation();    how can i send the project on this forum so u can see it entirly